# Rss feeder architecture

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, rss

I'm ASP.NET programmer with no WinForms knowledge.

I need to create a service that will access few online rss feeds, save them in jSon format and then pass them to page on user request. Application that will consume rss feeds in jSon format is MVC application. So translation services can be integrated inside of MVC application.

What would you advice to start with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx)** class from `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` namespace.

This namespace contains all the classes you need to create or consume RSS / Atom feeds.